# Eclipse regex find and replace

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to replace the below statement

```
ImageIcon("images/calender.gif");
```

with

```
ImageIcon(res.getResource("images/calender.gif"));
```

Can anyone suggest a regex to do this in eclipse.Instead of "calender.gif" any filename can come.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find this pattern (in regex mode):

```
ImageIcon\(("[^"]+")\)
```

and replace with:

```
ImageIcon(res.getResource($1))
```

The `\(` and `\)` in the pattern escapes the braces since they are to match literally. The unescaped braces `(…)` sets up capturing group 1 which matches the doublequoted string literal, which should not have escaped doublequotes (which I believe is illegal for filenames anyway).

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

The `+` is one-or-more repetition, so `[^"]+` matches non-empty sequence of everything except double quotes. We simply surround this pattern with `"` to match the double-quoted string literal.

So the pattern breaks down like this:

```
      literal(   literal)
         |          |
ImageIcon\(("[^"]+")\)
           \_______/
            group 1
```

In replacement strings, `$1` substitutes what group 1 matched.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Brackets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
  - [Examples/Programming Constructs - Strings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html) - has patterns for strings that may contain escaped doublequotes

Comment: Can you explain the above regex.

Comment: @Emil: note that this will not handle e.g. `ImageIcon(getPath() + getFilename())` and funky things like that. A general Java expression is not regular, so a universal solution should use something other than regex.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-F

Find: `ImageIcon\("([^\"]*)"\);`

Replace with: `ImageIcon(res.getResource("\1"));`

Check `Regular Expressions` checkbox.